# mvc3 : determine if an url will result in the execution of a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm doing some jobs in my global.asax `Application_AcquireRequestState` event, and I would like to do that job *only* if the current url (`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`) match any registered route.

In fact, I don't want to execute code for requests on images, JavaScript or any other file.

So the question is: is there an easy way to test a given url against the routes collection, just to know if it match any route. I don't need to know *which* route it matches, just a true or false would do the job.

### Edit

The answer from archil works, but almost any url match a route. It makes me realize that my question is not correct. What I want if knowing if a given url will somehow result in the execution of a controller. A request on /Content/site.css *may* match a route, but *will not* execute a controller.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContextWrapper = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(Context);
    bool isMatch = false;

    foreach (var item in RouteTable.Routes)
    {
        if (item.GetRouteData(httpContextWrapper) != null)
        {
            isMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

From summary of RouteBase.GetRouteData

```
//     An object that contains the values from the route definition if the route
//     matches the current request, or null if the route does not match the request.
public abstract RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext);
```

**UPDATE:**

To filter also by route handler(that is, urls that will be handled by mvc framework, not urls corresponding to css and js files) I added check for `RouteData.RouteHandler`

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContextWrapper = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(Context);
    bool isMatch = false;

    foreach (var item in RouteTable.Routes)
    {
        RouteData routeData = null;
        if ((routeData = item.GetRouteData(httpContextWrapper)) != null && routeData.RouteHandler.GetType().Equals(typeof(MvcRouteHandler)))
        {
            isMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to works perfectly, but by trying it I realize that that's not what I need. My goal is to deal only whit urls that will be handled by controllers. The reqest "http://localhost:8080/Content/print-styles.css" match a rule, but will not instanciate a controller. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found something working :

```
  private static bool IsRoutedRequest()
  {
     IHttpHandler handler = HttpContext.Current.Handler;
     return handler != null && handler is MvcHandler;
  }
```